# Working with an existing Grunt project - Getting JSHint Missing semicolon and errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, jshint

In an existing GRUNT project (http://gruntjs.com/getting-started), I did npm install and then grunt and I'm getting loads of JSHint errors (missing semicolon, mixed spaces and tabs, extra comma, etc ). I know the project was working on a different system.

**error description:**

```
Running "jshint:beforeconcat" (jshint) task
Linting js/filters/empFilter.js...ERROR
[L22:C4] Missing semicolon.
}])
```

**angularjs file with error**

```
angular.module ("app").filter('empFilter', [function () {
   return function (emps, username) {
      /*some code*/

      return emps;

   };
}])  /* <--- error at this line */
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "test_app",
    "version": "0.0.11",
    "path": "http://127.0.0.1/TestApp/",
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "~0.4.1",
        "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.1.20130516",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.1.2",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.1.1",
        "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.4.0",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.0",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.1.1",
        "grunt-contrib-yuidoc": "~0.4.0",
        "grunt-karma": "~0.4.4",
        "grunt-open": "~0.2.0",
        "grunt-bumpx": "~0.1.0",
        "autoprefixer": "~0.4.20130515",
        "grunt-git": "0.0.1",
        "grunt-devtools": "0.1.0-7"
    }
}
```

**JSHint options in gruntFile.js**

```
jshint: {
            options: {
                "globals": {
                    "asi": false, 
                    "ga": true,
                    "FileReader": true,
                    "html2canvas": true,
                    "console": true,
                    "angular": true,
                    "$": true,
                    "window": true,
                    "screen": true,
                    "Image": true,
                    "clearTimeout": true,
                    "setTimeout": true,
                    "document": true,
                    "localStorage": true,
                    "sessionStorage": true,
                    "device": true,
                    "navigator": true,
                    "io": true,
                    "createjs": true,
                    "lib": true,
                    "platform": true,
                    "inherits": true,
                    "signals": true,
                    "Date": true
                }
            }
```

I do not want to update the files based o the errors because the project worked ok on another system. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Seems you missed the point of jshint. It tells you that there is linting errors. The code you pasted clearly is missing a ; . It is not about if the code works or not, it is about the linting.

Comment: So what do you want to do about it? You can either fix the errors, ignore them or make jshint more relaxing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the other system had a `.jshintrc` file that had lenient linting options in it, and perhaps this file was not added to source control.